# Get "php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: Name or service not known" when try to run php builtin server in composer

Tags: php, docker

This is my `Dockerfile`

```
FROM php:7.1
COPY ./ /var/www/html
WORKDIR /var/www/html
CMD ["php", "-S 0.0.0.0:8181 -t /var/www/html"]
EXPOSE 8181
```

Run it `docker run -p 8181:8181 my-app`

and receive error

`[Mon Sep  4 23:47:39 2017] Failed to listen on  0.0.0.0:8181 (reason: php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: Name or service not known)`

I don't understand what I'm doing wrong

This version works:

```
FROM php
RUN echo "<?php echo 'Hello World';" > /tmp/index.php
CMD ["php", "-S", "0.0.0.0:80", "-t", "/tmp"]
```

but this is doesn't

```
FROM php
COPY ./ /var/www
CMD ["php", "-S 0.0.0.0:80", "-t", "/var/www"]
```

Comment: Is there a reason you're using `0.0.0.0` over `localhost`?

Comment: I used `localhost` as well. And received same error

Answer (score 3):

When using *exec* form, you need to separate each param, ie

```
CMD ["php", "-S", "0.0.0.0:8181", "-t", "/var/www/html"]
```